# TFTP trouble: timeout before file found

Tags: command-line, 12.04, tftp

I've installed TFTP to the best of my knowledge and am trying to perform a basic function test of:

```
get uImage
```

When run as a normal user, I get permission denied. When using `sudo` it replies back

```
Transfer timed out.
```

With the verbose mode on, it gives me:

```
getting from localhost:uImage to uImage [netascii]
Transfer timed out.
```

I have no idea what's gone wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try on this way. Work for me.

Install following packages.

```
sudo apt-get install xinetd tftpd tftp
```

Create /etc/xinetd.d/tftp

and put this entry

```
service tftp
{
protocol        = udp
port            = 69
socket_type     = dgram
wait            = yes
user            = nobody
server          = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
server_args     = /tftpboot
disable         = no
}
```

Create a folder /tftpboot this should match whatever you gave in server_args. mostly it will be tftpboot

```
sudo mkdir /tftpboot
sudo chmod -R 777 /tftpboot
sudo chown -R nobody /tftpboot
```

Restart the xinetd service.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/xinetd restart
```

Comment: done all, till I got **command not found** after trying the restart. xinetd does exist, however its simply not restarting. **ls -l** gave me _Lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Dec 6 2010 xinetd -> /lib/init/upstart-job_

Comment: First command install xinetd. Please check again. I running tftp server on my pc configured on this way,

Comment: purged and reinstalled, before trying `sudo service xinetd restart`...Worked like a treat, rtfp also worked after that. Apologies for not thinking to use `service`.